# Generating an integer and use it as index for string array

Tags: java, android

I recently started with android programming, with just basic knowledge in java.
I'm having trouble with my code,What I'm aiming is to display a randomly chosen text that's already programmed in my array after the button is clicked (onclick event).

```
public void magicbegins() //
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 3;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    //generating random number from 0 to 3 to use as index in later event
    String[] magictext = {"yes", "no", "maybe"};

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //using the generated number as index for programmed string array
    text.setText(magictext[rand]);
}
```

If any case this codes is not recommendable to use, will anyone provide a sample script that would do similar from what I aim at very least?

Comment: You'll want `int rand = r.nextInt( max - min ) + min;`. In this specific case, you can just use `rand = r.nextInt( max );`

Comment: +1, when min is 0, it serves no purpose to add/subtract it anywhere. That being said, it works in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your index needs to be 0, 1, or 2, just use `r.nextInt(3)` (or, if you reorder the variable declarations, `r.nextInt(magictext.length)`). You certainly should not be using `r.nextInt(max - min + 1)` since that will occasionally give 3, which is an out-of-bounds index.

This formula:

```
r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

is appropriate when `min` and `max` both need to be included in the generated range of random integers. When the desired range is up to, but not including, `max`, the formula should be:

```
r.nextInt(max - min) + min
```

My suggestion is to use this, but with 0 and 3 substituted for `min` and `max`, respectively.

You might also consider moving `magictext` and `r` out of the method and make them member fields of the class. You can do the same thing with the `text` field, so you don't need to be looking it up each time. You can initialize the `text` field in your `onCreate` method. Your code would then look like this:

```
private final Random r = new Random();
private final String[] magictext = {"yes", "no", "maybe"};
private TextView text;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    . . . // what you have now, followed by
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

public void magicbegins()
{
    int rand = r.nextInt(magictext.length);

    text.setText(magictext[rand]);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: ahh thank you, it must be the random integer that causes the program failure at time,.. thank you accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

As @Ted Hopp Suggested

use this

```
public void magicbegins() 
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(3);
    String[] magictext = {"yes", "no", "maybe"};

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    text.setText(magictext[rand]);
}
```

Comment: As He is new so I thing full code is good for him..Sorry about that

Comment: I just use its code in actual code what Hobo wants and Ted changed his code later..

Answer (score 0):

[Random#nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this
>   random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is
>   that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated
>   and returned. All n possible int values are produced with
>   (approximately) equal probability.

```
int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

which can generate 3 .Since your array has only 3 elements its index will be 0,1,2. Trying to access magictext[3] will cause  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Comment: That's not an answer, just a restatement of the problem.